# Is it possible to develop an Entity Layer with ANSI C/C++ or Embedded C to be used both in Android & iPhone platforms?

Tags: iphone, c++, android, c

I need to create a common entity layer for my mobile phone application developments.(especially iPhone and Android platforms).Later on I want to develop some parts of business logic and interfaces with specific tools /languages used to develop for those two platforms.

(I've been searching about cross mobile frameworks and I know about most of the popular ones.
Rhodes,PhoneGap,Appcelerator,Corona,MoSync,Sencha Touch,jQuery etc.
People made various combinations with those frameworks to create native,native-like,mobile web based applications.
To create a cross platform application **is not my main goal**.)

This blogpost suggests ANSI C/C++ for porting applications across iOS and Android platforms.
http://community.developer.motorola.com/t5/MOTODEV-Blog/Porting-apps-from-iOS-to-Android-devices/ba-p/11144

Due to this blogpost I think it is possible to create an entity layer to be mapped and used on two platforms.

Had anybody ever tried to achieve this? Or know any other way to implement an entity layer to be used in both iPhone and Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using ANSI C/C++, i.e. standard C/C++ without extensions, it will make an easier porting, but it also depends on the libraries (libc version an so on). With Android you can either use the JNI or code a native activity, but obviously that isn't portable and the idea of using native code is performance, not portability.